# no authentification with keycloak on ionic3 in hybrid app

Tags: angular, cordova, docker, ionic3, keycloak

I need your help about authentication with keycloak in hybrid app.

I run keycloak with docker. I'm programming a mobile app with ionic3, angular@4.1.3 and cordova.

I created my realm "demo", and a client "demo-client" with valid Redirect URL = http://localhost and Web Origins = http://localhost. 
I've upload to my apps this package.json:

```
{
  "realm": "demo",
  "auth-server-url": "http://192.168.238.60:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "demo-client",
  "public-client": true
}
```

I've also added the whiltelist and inappbrowser plugins.

When I start my app and click on login, I get the login page of keycloak in the inappbrowser. I sign up and I go back to my application perfeclty. However I'm still not authenticated in my app, but my session is perfectly open in the keycloak admin console.

It seems I don't get the token and session information back from the keycloak server in my application.

There is no information of any kind using those technologies on the internet. If someone has already been into those issues, it will be very nice of you to help me.

One last thing, when I open my app on the browser with "ionic serve", everything is working find. Authentification works!!

=>It seems information is not caught from browser back to app.

Here is how I initialize keycloak.

On the main.ts

```
KeycloakProvider.init({ onLoad: "check-sso",checkLoginIframe: false })
  .then(() => {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  })
  .catch((e: string) => {
    console.log('Error in ng2 bootstrap: ' + e);
 });
```

And the provider is:

```
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-js');

@Injectable()
export class KeycloakProvider {
  static keycloakAuth: KeycloakInstance = Keycloak("assets/keycloak.json");

  static init(options?: any): Promise<any> {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(KeycloakProvider.keycloakAuth));
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      KeycloakProvider.keycloakAuth.init(options)
        .success(() => {
          resolve();
        })
        .error((errorData: any) => {
          reject(errorData);
        });
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the JS code for the KC init part ?

Comment: no one??? @SébastienBlanc do you need more code samples? Thank you for your help.

Comment: It has been a long time I didn't test the lib against Cordova, could you show me where you noticed you don't have a token ? Or better, could you share a sample app so I can replay it ?

Comment: you can find the login part of the project in https://github.com/tomalaforge/login-app.git

Comment: Did someone find anything? I've been struggling with this for more than a week. Any help of any kind will be very appreciated. Help might just be any thing I can try, this has not to be the solution. Thank you for any one desired to help.

Comment: @Thomas did you resolved this ??